# Dose any infinite dimensional subspace contain the range of some one to one bounded linear operator?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let M be a dense infinite dimensional subspace in a Hilbert space H. Is there some bounded linear one-to-one operator T on H such that Ran(T) $\subseteq$ M?

Comment: No. Take the linear subspace of finitely supported vectors in $\ell^2$. I wonder what is the example of the person who downvoted...

Comment: Same as yours, fedja.

Comment: Is anyone easily able to characterize the possible sorts of subspaces that _might_ be these images? Without thinking too much about it, the thought insinuates itself on me that this question might encode a great many profound (and not presently answerable) questions.

Comment: @paul garrett We can certainly discuss that but I'd like to see the looming closure relieved first. One way to do it is to ask a new question in the form that would provoke such a discussion. Do you want to do it, Paul?

Comment: Thank you for your answer fedja, but it should be explain that how the linear subspace of finitely supported vectors in $\ell^2$  can not contain the range of any one-to-one operator?

Comment: @paulgarrett: If $R(T)$ is dense itself, then the self-adjoint operator $TT^*$ is still injective, so the spectral theorem clarifies the situation in this case. In general, I don't know right now, but it somehow doesn't look to me like it will be terribly deep (though I might be wrong, of course).

Comment: Operator ranges are well studied.  Googling "operator ranges" yields many relevant hits.

Comment: First of all, for any $n$, you can find a unit vector $v_n$ such that $Tv_n$ has a non-zero coordinate corresponding to the index $m>n$. Now make a sum $v=\sum_n a_nv_n$ with random $a_n\in (0,n^{-2})$. Then $Tv=\sum a_nTv_n$ has infinitely many non-zero coordinates with probability $1$. @Bill Johnson You are right, of course, but my experience with googling key words for a simple question is that you get a lot of highly sophisticated papers for each of which it takes more effort to figure out if the answer is there than to solve the problem yourself :-)

Comment: I wish people had voted to migrate this to Math.SE where it could get a real answer.  But anyway, I think it is false even if we drop the word "bounded"; by Baire category, the Hamel dimension of an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is $> \aleph_0$ (and in fact it can be shown it is at least $\mathfrak{c}$), hence the same is true of any injective linear image. But a separable Hilbert space has dense subspaces of Hamel dimension $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @fedja: Randomness is not really necessary (if that is worth pointing out), you can also find $a_n$'s recursively: just choose $a_{n+1}\not=0$ so small that the previous non-zero components that matter always stay above $1/2$ their original value.